# Rich native client for MSDN library documentation

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, documentation, msdn

The [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms123401.aspx) provides great documentation for .NET/C#. However, the primary delivery medium, HTML via a web browser is suboptimal. A rich native Windows client for browsing this documentation seems like a perfect opportunity to showcase WPF. Is there such a client available? Are there any alternative interfaces to the MSDN Library?

Comment: It might not be what you are looking for, but Visual Studio's Help viewer is in WPF, and displays the MSDN Library, which you can download. However, it's just a wrapper for a Web Browser component ;)

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2010 can download the help to your local hard drive and load it from local server (it actually does use a local server, so search etc. works). Everything is seamless - you browse the documentation directly in VS itself. Hitting F1 with caret on a symbol will direct the searches into this local browser.

The help is to some extent integrated into the VS editor itself (for example as parameter info). [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) goes slightly further and displays even more info:

[image]

You can also browse the .Net code with some documentation bits in [Object Browser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbs280h1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Other than these, I don't know about anything - but I also don't know what features you would like. I personally think the old documentation browser present in VS <=2008 was horrible.

There are some features I would like to see which are currently not available anywhere as far as I know (for example [list of implementors of an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398382/how-to-find-out-a-list-of-types-in-base-class-library-that-implement-specific-in)), but the solutions I listed are mostly all I personally need.

Comment: Yeah, the Object Browser is pretty nice! It would be nice if there were a keystroke in VS to jump to help for the current item (like F1 does with MSDN Library).

Comment: @dharmatech ReSharper adds this to the context menu under Navigate To -> Object Browser. And since it is a menu command, keyboard shortcut can be assigned to it (it has awkward name "EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.NavigateTo.Resharper_NavigateToObjectBrowser" in keyboard settings). If you don't have Resharper, you may try the free add-in Productivity Power Tools, it may have that feature as well.